# If the statistics are gathered for a table in oracle database when its empty , then what is the way to restore the original statistics for the table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, query-optimization

The table in question here works in the following way:
Lets consider the table in question here is table A and there are another two tables B and C.
Table C receives first receives all the data from external system.
Data then gets transferred to table B where it is meant to be processed and a copy of that data also get created in table A.As the data continues to process in table B, the status of the data changes in both A and B. Once all the data gets processed in table B, tables gets deleted from table A.

So basically table A queues up the data which is to be processed by table B.

Somehow statistics got gathered in the table A when it was empty although table A at a specific time holds thousands of records.
Hence the sample size of the table became zero. Is there any way the original statistics can be restored in the table.

Read in the oracle site that the restore procedure of dbms_stats package is helpful in restoring the original statistics. But is there any other way of doing it? And will the restoration of statistics helpful in reviving the performance of processing?

Comment: Why not just recompute the statistics of the table after it was updated?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to proceed seem to just recompute the statistics whenever you need fresh ones. Of course, this is relevant only if stats computation is not too long.

---

Else, the [`RESTORE_TABLE_STATS` Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_stats.htm#i1046561) is probably the simplest way to go:

> This procedure restores statistics of a table as of a specified timestamp (as_of_timestamp). The procedure will restore statistics of associated indexes and columns as well.

Consider:

```
exec dbms_stats.restore_table_stats(
    ownname => 'myschema',
    tabname => 'mytable',
    as_of_timestamp => 'mytimestamp'
);
```

---

Finally, another option would be to manually export/import the statistics, following these steps:

- create the table statistics using the [`CREATE_STAT_TABLE Procedure`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_stats.htm#i1035018)
- export the statistics at the relevant moment, using [`EXPORT_TABLE_STATS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_stats.htm#i1035814)
- when needed, reimport the stats using [`IMPORT_TABLE_STATS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_stats.htm#i1037419)

[This blog link](https://blog.dbi-services.com/how-to-retrieve-previous-table-statistics-using-oracle-dbmsstats/) provides a detailed example on how to proceed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your inputs. But I have one more question. Will restoring the statistics revive the performance?

Comment: @user12067366: if the current table data looks like what it was at the time when the statistics were saved (number of records, repartition of data within columns, etc...), yes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to regathering stats and restoring stats, as suggested by GMB, you might also want to lock the table's statistics.  Locking stats can prevent bad stats from happening in the first place.

Run code like this to lock the stats:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.lock_table_stats
    (
        ownname => 'SOME_USER',
        tabname => 'SOME_TABLE'
    );
end;
/
```

That table will be excluded from automatic statistics gathering processes.  If a process tries to gather stats manually, without first unlocking the table, it will raise the error "ORA-20005: object statistics are locked (stattype = ALL)".

Comment: Thanks Jon for your inputs. Actually the table statistics stay locked only. They were unlocked to gather stats and one of the tables for which statistics gathering was not required was also included in statistics gather command.If possible, can you give your inputs on the below points:1. If stats are restored, then would the performance revive? 2. Is there any other way of restoring the lost statistics. Will look forward to your response